# NSOperation Queue executes only first operation and stop executing after that

Tags: objective-c, nsoperation

I am trying to execute custom operations in NSOperation Queue,
But the problem is 
it executes only the first operation in queue and not execute the rest of them.
Please resolve this issue.

here is my code:

```
for (ContentMediaModel *uploadMedia in mediaArray)
{
    AmazonUpload *customOperation = [[AmazonUpload alloc]    initWithData:uploadMedia];
    [operationQueue addOperation:customOperation];
}
```

here is my custom Operation class:

```
 @implementation AmazonUpload

-(AmazonUpload *)initWithData:(ContentMediaModel *)uploadMedia
{
if (self = [super init])
 {
    self.uploadMedia=uploadMedia;
    executing = YES;
    finished = NO;
}

 return self;
}

-(void)start
{
 NSLog(@"** operation starts **");

[self main];
}

-(void)main
{
if ([self isCancelled])
{
    NSLog(@"** operation cancelled **");
}

NSLog(@"** operation executing **");
[[AmazonS3Manager sharedInstance] uploadFile:self.uploadMedia.media.filename     showLoader:NO];
}

-(BOOL)isConcurrent
{
 return YES;
}

-(BOOL)isExecuting
{
 return executing;
}

-(BOOL)isFinished
{
 return finished;
}
@end
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];` after your for loop.

Comment: i did but it just made my app irresponsive.

Comment: You never mark the operation as finished.

Comment: Can you format your code? Is `uploadFile` an async operation?